# For higher version of node > 17.9.1 npm pack is not packing "bundledDependencies"

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

Recently I was upgrading Node.js version that I am using to my project, while doing so I found that using `npm pack` command to generate the `.tgz` tarball file is ignoring/not packing the `bundledDependencies` in the project.

With lower version of Node.js < 17.9.1 the `npm pack` command is working fine, meaning it is able to pack the `bundledDependencies` properly resulting in correct tgz file.

`package.json` of the folder that I want to pack looks like this:

```json
{
    "name": "viewer-ng13",
    "version": "1.0",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^13.3.0",
        "@angular/core": "^13.3.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^2.3.0"
    },
    "bundledDependencies": [
        "core-3d",
        "loader",
        "viewer",
        "shared-ui"
    ]
}
```

The Folder structure is like below

```
release-ng
--viewer-ng13
----esm2020
----lib
----index.d.ts
----package.json
----nodemodules
------core-3d
------loader
------viewer
------shared-ui
```

So bundled dependencies are inside the `node_modules/` folder.

I am expecting that like lower versions of Node.js I should be able to build .tgz file with higher/upgraded versions of Node.js.